# WSR Show Numbers

Tags: c#, windows, clickable

In Windows Speech Recognition (WSR), there is a command called "Show Numbers" that pulls up transparent boxes over every clickable item on the active window.

I'm not looking for a full program but more of what identifies clickable items on an active screen, if something like that even exists. I hope this question makes sense. Thank You! If it's important, I'm using c#.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with WSR, UI items can be identified through the UI Automation framework. It's able to see controls on windows and able to interact with them. The primary intent is for accessibility purposes(Screen readers and the like) but it has also been coopted for UI Automation tasks and is the backbone behind portions of the Coded UI Framework. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx